# Choropleth with dropdown menu to change data. Traces not showing

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

i am trying to produce a choropleth map in which the user can use a dropdown menu to change between different variables using plotly in R.
When doing something similar with a line chart, I could set the visibility of the second trace to FALSE and use a button to change the visibility of the different traces, as shown in the code below. However, when using plot_geo(), the plot only changes the color, the data and hoverinfo does not change. Also, the color switches back to the first trace as soon as the slider gets used.

If the user selects "stat2", I want the plot to only show the data, color and hoverinfo for this variable.

Thanks in advance!

```
df <- data.frame(year=c(rep(2000,5), rep(2001,5), rep(2002,5), rep(2003,5), rep(2004,5), rep(2005,5)),
                 stat1=sample(1:10, 30, replace=T),
                 stat2=sample(1:100, 30),
                 location=rep(c("DEU", "BEL", "FRA", "ITA", "SWE", "FIN"),5))

                 y=1,# position the button
                 buttons = list(  
                   list(method="update",
                        args=list(list(visible=list(T,F))),
                        label="stat1"), 
                   list(method="update",
                        args=list(list(visible=list(F,T))),
                        label="stat2")))

plot_geo(df, frame=~year) %>% 
  add_trace(locations=~location, z=~stat1, color=~stat1, colorscale="Blues") %>%
  add_trace(locations=~location, z=~stat1, color=~stat2, colorscale="Greys", visible=F) %>%
  layout(geo=list(scope="europe"),
         updatemenus=list(button))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the data of the second trace is not shown"? What data are you referring to? If you are referring to the color bars, those changed. If you're referring to the animation, it shows both traces, but it sticks to the shades of blue for all. The hover content is present for both. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Thank you very much! I updated the question, I hope it is clearer now.